# Android/iOS: In-app SQL calls or web backend?

Tags: android, ios, sql, web-services

We're a couple of beginner devolpers in the startup phase of an iOS/Android application, and we're looking into how to setup the database/application connection. What are the pros/cons of using a direct connection to the DB from the application? And what are the pros/cons of using a web backend, using php/json? We've done some research and found backend services like parse and stackmob, but we're pretty sure we want to build our own if a web based service is a must.

Thanks in advance,
Christopher and Christian

Answer (score 0):

This is not about pros and cons, this is about what you need. Do you need to access a server, e.g. user authentication, sharing data between users, access data which change often? If yes, use a server backend, otherwise make the application working offline.

Comment: Thats not really what Im asking. What I want to know is if it's some kind of security risk to connect directly to my SQL server from the app, and that I therefore need to access it through a web backend.